# R Studio: use xtable to create html file

Tags: html, r, statistics, export-to-html

Hoping someone can assist me in exporting my imported .csv file into an *.html file using xtable package.

Below is what I have written so far but when I check my folder the file is not there.  Any insight or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

This is what was done to import my csv data file to then export as *.html file:

```
Data=file.path("C:\\Users\\aacha\\OneDrive\\School\\Active Courses\\BIT-430 Intro to Business Analytics\\Week 5-Intro to a Statistical Language\\Topic 5 Data\\Data.csv")
Sales=read.csv(Data, header = TRUE, sep = ',')
View(Sales)
install.packages("xtable")
library("xtable")
```

**Below is my attempt to create the *.html file**

```
Sales.xtable=xtable(Sales)
xtable(Sales)
print(xtable(Sales.xtable,type = "html"), file = "C:\\Users\\aacha\\OneDrive\\School\\Active Courses\\BIT-430 Intro to Business Analytics\\Week 5-Intro to a Statistical Language\\Sales.txt"
```

Comment: small comment: you don't need to call `xtable()` twice, you've already made an `xtable` object with the first call.

Comment: other quick comment, do you have write permissions to the folder?